# Stair edge bumper with residential aesthetic

Tags: stairs, treads

The stairs in my house have sharp, painful edges. I’ve been looking for something to add a rounded and/or padded edge. I need it to be a) grippy (or at least not slick), b) durable, and c) substantial enough to actually soften the edges. I *want* it to be d) cheap, and e) fit a residential aesthetic.

So far, I have tried three options:

1. Carpet treads. I only found one product that fit my shallow (9.25”) tread depth. The main weakness of these is that they don’t span the width of the treads.
   [image]
2. This rubber stair edge trim. The main weakness of this is I don’t like how it looks - industrial, out of place in a home.
   [image]
3. This silicone edge protector. The main weakness here is that I don’t think it will hold up. The material is soft, and the adhesive portion is narrow.
   [image]

I would love to have something like option 2, but clear. I haven’t been able to find such a product.

Any suggestions?

Update: I went with option 3, the silicone edge protector. It's been surprisingly durable so far. Option 2 started delaminating after a few days of testing.

Comment: What are the stairs made of? Could you not just round the edge over with a plane or electric router?

Comment: @PeteKirkham They are oak. I don’t want to remove the finish.

Comment: You won't if the thought of refinishing scares you; but a good solution would be to glue new (rounded) wooden noses to each tread, addressing the shape AND the excessively narrow treads. As for the carpet product not being full width, look at the wear pattern on any old set of steps - nobody walks out there at the extreme edges.

Comment: Full carpet runners are also an option, and not particular as to tread width/depth. Of course, they hide most of the stairs with carpet...

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks for the suggestions. I think if I were going to do something that required a professional, I’d go with the deeper, bull-nose tread option. But that (and full waterfall carpeting) are outside the budget right now.

Comment: How about these?  You don't say how wide your treads are, but worst case, you can trim: https://www.amazon.com/Bullnose-Self-Adhesive-Non-Slip-Washable-Removable/dp/B09CNQMNX2

Comment: Please undelete your answer and remove the answer from the question. That's not how SE sites work.

Comment: @FreeMan I realized that my update wasn’t a proper answer. The question (is there a clear residential stair corner bumper available for purchase) is still open.

Comment: In that case, this is a shopping question that is off topic.